# How do you write a query that takes into account multiple numbers and orders them

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My data looks something like this:

```
{_id: ObjectId("5e10c2d61a9201e439335816"), name: "Bob", redWins: 23, blueWins: 34}
{_id: ObjectId("5e10c34e1a9201e439335818"), name: "Alice", redWins: 41, blueWins: 52}
{_id: ObjectId("5e10c36f1a9201e439335819"), name: "John", redWins: 12, blueWins: 24}
```

The goal is to be able to sort the data from most to least total wins (redWins + blueWins) and have a result that has the name and the amount of total wins in it. Desired output:

```
{name: "Alice", totalWins: 93},
{name: "Bob", totalWins: 57},
{name: "John", totalWins: 36}
```

One of the things I tried to use aggregation but I can't seem to figure out how to add the numbers before sorting them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) with [$sum](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields: {
           totalWins: {$sum: ["$redWins", "$blueWins"]}
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            totalWins: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            name: 1,
            totalWins: 1,
            _id: 0
        }
    }
])
```